# How many teaspoon of milk is needed to melt 50g of chocolate?

Tags: melting-chocolate

I am melting some chocolate on pan so I read that melting with water cause some lumps, and told that to use milk. So I want to know how much milk I need to use. I am using normal Cadbury Diary Milk chocolate bar approx of 50g.

Comment: You don't need to add any liquid to chocolate in order to melt it, it will melt fine just by itself. What are you trying to make?

Comment: @GdD I want to make chocolate converted banana pops so I thought milk must be added so chocolate will be smooth and melt quickly. Isn't that it?

Comment: No, on the contrary you don't want to add any milk at all. You would want to melt the chocolate in a bain marie or very gently in the microwave, dip your banana pops in it, and then let them cool and solidify.

Comment: @GdD Won't chocolate stick at bottom of pan ? How do I prevent it? Sorry I am new in cooking

Comment: Melted chocolate is a bit sticky, but you can just scrape it off the bottom with a rubber spatula or a spoon. Don't melt it directly on the pan, use a bain marie - ie a bowl on top of a small pot filled with hot water. Then let it cool a little bit before dipping. Pour any excess into a mold and let it solidify, no need to throw it away.

Comment: @ShubhamWagh google "Bain Marie" and you'll find out.  It's a way of heating very gently , and is probably easier than microwaving if you want to see what's going on.  There are times you'd add some milk to melted chocolate (often after melting) but this isn't one of them.

Comment: A chocolate sauce/topping with milk/cream added in is called a ganache, and behaves different from plain melted chocolate. Is that what you want?

Comment: @rackandboneman I never heard it but I just wanted melted chocolate and microwave did that. thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need any milk to melt chocolate. The goal with melting chocolate is to keep it within a range of heat so that it doesn't burn or separate.

A bain-marie is a technique where you place a heat-proof bowl over a pot of simmering water to heat the contents of the bowl slowly.  If you're melting chocolate for dipping bananas, I would recommend using the microwave technique (mentioned in the comments).  It's a lot easier. Just do short bursts (10-15 seconds) and stir in between each round.

Aside: If you want to go all out, you can read about [tempering chocolate](http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/how-to-temper-chocolate-356869). Tempering chocolate will help the chocolate set with a nice shine.  It will also set at room temperature.  I avoid all this and throw the bananas in the freezer for a few minutes after dipping them in chocolate. I hope this helps!